# How to removing certain core Gutenberg blocks on some Page Templates / Post Type

Tags: wordpress, hook, wordpress-gutenberg

As per WordPress,

```php
apply_filters_deprecated( 'allowed_block_types', bool|string[] $allowed_block_types, WP_Post $post )
```

> Warning: This hook has been deprecated. Use the ‘allowed_block_types_all’ filter instead.

Below code is not working now.

```php
add_filter('allowed_block_types', function($block_types, $post) {
  $allowed_blocks = [
    'core/shortcode',
    'core/image',
    'core/gallery',
    'core/heading',
    'core/quote',
  ];
  if ($post->post_type == 'page') {
    return $block_types;
  }
  else
  {
    $blocks_to_remove = [
      'acf/editor-intro',
    ];
    return array_diff($allowed_blocks, $blocks_to_remove);
  }
}, 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below hook I have created some conditions like **Post Types** / **Page Templates** / **etc.**

```php
add_filter('allowed_block_types_all', function ( $block_editor_context, $editor_context ) {
    if ($editor_context->post_type == 'page') {
        // Here you can check any Post Types
        return array(
            'core/paragraph',
            'core/heading',
            'core/list',
            'core/quote', // Above are few example
            'acf/test-block' // you can allow disable custom ACF blocks also
            );
    } else if (basename(get_page_template()) == 'template-custom.php') {
        // Here you can check any Custom Templates
        return array(
                'acf/test-block' // you can allow disable custom ACF blocks also
        );
    } else {
        // Here will return all default blocks
        return $block_editor_context;
    }
}, 10, 2 );
```

Below are some default blocks so you can remove as per required with hook.

| Block Types |
| --- |
| core/shortcode |
| core/image |
| core/gallery |
| core/heading |
| core/quote |
| core/embed |
| core/list |
| core/separator |
| core/more |
| core/button |
| core/pullquote |
| core/table |
| core/preformatted |
| core/code |
| core/html |
| core/freeform |
| core/latest-posts |
| core/categories |
| core/cover |
| core/text-columns |
| core/verse |
| core/video |
| core/audio |
| core/block |
| core/paragraph |
| core-embed/twitter |
| core-embed/youtube |
| core-embed/facebook |
| core-embed/instagram |
| core-embed/wordpress |
| core-embed/soundcloud |
| core-embed/spotify |
| core-embed/flickr |
| core-embed/vimeo |
| core-embed/animoto |
| core-embed/cloudup |
| core-embed/collegehumor |
| core-embed/dailymotion |
| core-embed/funnyordie |
| core-embed/hulu |
| core-embed/imgur |
| core-embed/issuu |
| core-embed/kickstarter |
| core-embed/meetup-com |
| core-embed/mixcloud |
| core-embed/photobucket |
| core-embed/polldaddy |
| core-embed/reddit |
| core-embed/reverbnation |
| core-embed/screencast |
| core-embed/scribd |
| core-embed/slideshare |
| core-embed/smugmug |
| core-embed/speaker |
| core-embed/ted |
| core-embed/tumblr |
| core-embed/videopress |
| core-embed/wordpress-tv |

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this approach to remove certain blocks in the block editor for custom post types:

```
<?php
function disable_specific_blocks( $allowed_block_types, $post ) {
    // An array of block names to disable
    $disabled_blocks = array(
        'core/table',
        'core/image',
        'core/gallery',
    );
  
    // Use this condition to disable blocks on certain post types, otherwise you can remove this IF condition
    if ( $post->post_type === 'post' ) {
        $allowed_block_types = array_diff( $allowed_block_types, $disabled_blocks );
    }

    return $allowed_block_types;
}
add_filter( 'allowed_block_types_all', 'disable_specific_blocks', 10, 2 );
?>
```

I've also created a detailed guide here on [how to disable specific blocks on the block editor](https://jeffreycarandang.com/how-to-disable-specific-blocks-in-the-wordpress-gutenberg-block-editor/) if you want to check it out.